# scrapy different hxs Elements for HtmlResponse and Response

Tags: selector, response, scrapy

I want to load url-adresses from a database and crawl each page. Therefore i tried to start a parse-function manually
My Problem is that even if the response attribute of the parse-function is exactly the same as one called by HtmlResponse (both: <200 url>) there are different hxs generated: 
The one by the response-attribute is:

```
    <HtmlXPathSelector xpath="None data=u'<html lang="de" dir="ltr" class="client-'>
```

The one by the HtmlResponse-Attribute is just:

```
    <HtmlXPathSelector xpath="None data=u'<html>
```

Why is this?

If I try to get Response(url) i just get an AttributeError called: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode'

Thanks for helping

Comment: are you issuing Requests to the engine or trying to instantiate Response objects with a url yourself? Hm. What "generated" the hxs selector, your code?  Show us the code.